# flutter memory leak my widget in homescreen

Tags: flutter, dispose

[image]

this is the error cause when I return to home screen. Is there any way to solve this? I tried dispose my timer but it did not work

```
 bool containerClicked = false;
  int nextSpinValue = 0;
  int? widgetIndex = 0;
 

  
  var spinController = StreamController<int>.broadcast();
  void spin() => spinController.add(++nextSpinValue)



  @override
  void initState() {
    Redirects.drawerList();
   
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer!.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var mHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var mWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    var spinController = StreamController<int>.broadcast();
    int nextSpinValue = 0;

    void spin() => spinController.add(++nextSpinValue);
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 3), (timer) async {
      if (nextSpinValue >= 3) {
        nextSpinValue = 0;
      }
      spin();
    });
```

caused somewhere in setstate

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens due to the fact that `StreamController` has to be [closed](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/SynchronousStreamController/close.html). Otherwise, `StreamController` object stays in the memory even if the widget getting stream events no longer exists. `dispose()` is a good place to call the `close` method.

AFAIK it's a property of Flutter Controllers. You have to close them.